# How to animate JQuery addClass/removeClass functions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addclass, removeclass

I want to know how to animate JQuery addClass/removeClass functions?

for animate function, it seems that I have to put some CSS properties, but what about if I have a class which makes element displayed as block each time I trigger a click function, while all elements are displayed as hidden in CSS. How can I animate this process?

Here's my code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var allSlides = $('li');

    $('#nextSlide').click(function(){
        var nextSlide = $('.active').next();
        if (nextSlide.length == 0)
        {
            var nextSlide = allSlides.first();
        }
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        nextSlide.addClass('active');
        return false;
    });

    $('#prevSlide').click(function(){
        var prevSlide = $('.active').prev();
        if (prevSlide.length == 0)
        {
            var prevSlide = allSlides.last();
        }
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        prevSlide.addClass('active');
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hello CairoCoder find the solution below :)

Answer (score 15):

You can apply the CSS3 transition property to the element being manipulated with jQuery.  Here's an example with vendor prefixes:

```
element {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; // Chrome
    -moz-transition: all 2s; // Mozilla
    -o-transition: all 2s; // Opera
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQueryUI you can use the $.toggleClass(); function.

http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) or you can use CSS3 transitions:

```
#nextSlide, #prevSlide {
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: display .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: display .5s ease;
  -o-transition: display .5s ease;
}
.active {
  transition: display .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: display .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: display .5s ease;
  -o-transition: display .5s ease;
}
```

That should work for you. You can add any other transitions to by replacing `display` in the transition style.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely animate to add/remove class with jquery.Please check the format below

```
.removeClass( className [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Example code below

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeInBack" );
});
```

[Reference link](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/)

***NOTE:*** But you've to add **jquery-ui.js** file to make it work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Hope this will be helpful.
Thanks